# TortoiseSVN 1.6.8 missing repository browser in Branch/Tag "To URL" dialog?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

It seems that in TortoiseSVN 1.6.8 (on Windows), when you click the "To URL..." button in the Branch/Tag dialog, it now pops up a generic "browse for folders" dialog. It used to pop up a Repository Browser. Displaying a regular folder browser isn't much use, since you can't navigate to any of the tags/branches via the file system.

Does anyone know if this is a regression or a deliberate change? Any possible workarounds (other than reverting to 1.6.7, which works fine)?

Notes:

- I am running a repository on the local file system, which may yield different results to one going across a network.
- I'm definitely using an FSFS repository, so [changes to BDB access via file:///](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/tsvn_1.6_releasenotes.html#bdb-file) shouldn't apply.
- The only reference I could find to this problem is here: http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/browse_thread/thread/f3406d1bad89f1d9.

Comment: Another reference to this issue: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2603459#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same behavior, seems to be a bug. If the "url" is pointing to the root of the repository (without trunk and anything) the repository browser is displayed... kind of a workaround but still annoying.

**Edit:** And you are right: it is related to local repositories. I do not see this with server based repositories.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, the work-around sounds useful (I've just dropped back to 1.6.7 for the moment, but it could come in handy if this is an ongoing issue).

Answer (score 1):

The bug was fixed in 1.6.10 earlier this week.